# TypeError: data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I get the error:

```
TypeError: data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

when I execute:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithSGD


conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local")
.setAppName("Logistic Regression")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf) 


def mapper(line):
    feats = line.strip().split(",") 
    label = feats[len(feats) - 1]       # Last column is the label
    feats = feats[2: len(feats) - 1]    # remove id and type column
    feats.insert(0,label)
    features = [ float(feature) for feature in feats ] # need floats
    return np.array(features)

data = sc.textFile("test.csv")
parsedData = data.map(mapper)

# Train model
model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData)
```

I get the error on `model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData)` line.

`parsedData` is supposed to be an RDD. I am not sure why I am getting this.

Github link to [full source code](https://github.com/samarthbhargav/spark-example/blob/master/run-spark-ex.py)

Answer (score 1):

> parsedData is supposed to be an RDD. I am not sure why I am getting this.

Problem is not that `parsedData` is not `RDD`, problem is what it stores. As message says you need `RDD[LabeledPoint]` while you pass `RDD[numpy.ndarray]`:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

def mapper(line):
    ...
    return LabeledPoint(label, features)
```